# spark sql data bigger than node memory when coalesce(1)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, coalesce

I'm working on spark 1.6.1

I have a dataframe that is distributed and is for sure bigger than any nodes i have in my cluster.

What will happen if i bring all in a node ?

```
df.coalesce(1)
```

Will the job fail ?

Thanks

Comment: Short answer : Yes.

Comment: To add to eliasah's answer, it will fail with `OutOfMemory` Exception. There are many ways to circumvent the need of `coalesce`. What are you trying to achieve by bringing all the data to the driver?

Answer (score 1):

It will fail for sure as data will not fit in memory. 
If you want to return single file as a output, you can merge HDFS files later using HDFS getMerge.

You can use utility to merge multiple files into one file from below mentioned git project
https://github.com/gopal-tiwari/hdfs-file-merge